# share an image on FB wall

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have an image in my app which I want to share on FB.

Now I have FB app installed on my iPhone.

What I want is when I tap on share in the image of my app then it should open the FB app and allow me to share my image there.

Is it possible to share the image in our app through external FB app?

Same for twitter and linked in as well?

**SOLVED**
This was solved by using ShareKit. Only thing was you cannot directly post Image on twitter. So you have to upload image on your server and pass that URL to twitter. Sharekit rocks

Comment: Have you checked out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

Try using sharekit it is useful.. 
Follow all the step and if there is and query than post back

Answer (score 0):

read these tutorial to share an image on Facebook

http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app,
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

add FBConnect into your project and use below code for share capture image on facebook.
Also add delegate FBSessionDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, FBRequestDelegate into your .h file.
If you want to share local image than you don't need to upload image on server. pass uiimage object into facebook params.

```
if (facebook == nil) {
        facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"your facebook key "];


    }   


    NSArray* permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             @"publish_stream", @"offline_access", nil] ;
    //  
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

- (BOOL) takeScreenshot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);



    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   viewImage,@"message",                                   
                                   nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"   // or use page ID instead of 'me'
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];



    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FBSessionDelegate
/**
 * Called when the user has logged in successfully.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    isFBLogged = YES;   
    [self takeScreenshot];

    if([self takeScreenshot])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Image share sucessfully"
                              message: nil
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Image share unsucessfully"
                              message: nil
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }


}
```