# post image on Facebook wall and facebook friends wall

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am very tired with the problems of API, like Facebook Graph API, weather API etc.

I've used both API in my project. Graph API for Facebook and Google weather API for weather, but now on time of project completion, both API are not working. Google weather API depreciated in November,

And the Facebook features I've been using (post image on wall and post image on friend wall) were working last day, but now they don't.

The problem is that when I log in, I get the message `The page you requested is not Found` and below a link to go back to the previous page.

[image]

And when i click the link "back to previous page" it shows message:

```
An error has occurred with AppName, please try again
API error code : 100
API error Description : Invalid Parameter
Error_message : cancel_URL URL is not properly formatted
```

I wants to know solution of Facebook API. Is this problem is with every developer? if API modified or changed what we can do regarding?

Comment: please refer below links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240006/share-an-image-on-fb-wall/12006227#12006227

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138367/post-on-friends-wall-using-facebook-sdk-3-0-for-ios/12138738#12138738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long ago did you update your facebook API? About two weeks ago I had to remove my entire API, redownload, and change all the posting code my app was using. It stopped working entirely and had no idea until app users complained. Some necessary changes for the new facebook API:

Facebook recommends putting these in your appDelegate if you look at the newest sample apps.

```
    #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

     - (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
        NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil];
                return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                                      allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     if(state==513){
                   //facebook usage has been approved
                   }
                   }];
            }    

     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
                        openURL:(NSURL *)url
              sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
                     annotation:(id)annotation {
                // We need to handle URLs by passing them to FBSession in order for SSO authentication
                // to work.
                return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
            }
```

And whereever you want to make your post put something like this:

```
    if(facebookEnabled==YES)
    {

     NSString *fbText=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatever text you want to post";

            [FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:fbText
                                        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
{
                                                                                    }];
    }
```

Let me know if you have questions. Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry to revive this 1 year old post, but would you mind tell me what exactly is the meaning of the state 513? Is there a defined bit map whose value is 513 among all the `FBSessionState`s? Thank you!

Comment: No prob. From what i remember, it's just a code that changes dependent on whether or not the user has approved, denied, or whether there was an error. That line isn't even necessary though and I should have taken it out before posting haha. You really should just use the Social.Framework instead though. And the fb sdk has undoubtedly changed several times since this post. So that code is likely different now anyways. It's way easier to use than the sdk though

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was actually working with the FB SDK earlier today, and it seems that this code 513 still exists. The session state when the user just logged in is still 513, but I couldn't find any bit mask in the `FBSessionState`s that has that value. But anyway thanks for clearing up the mystery :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure it's your code's fault but Facebook is having issues right now.

My FB app in iOS doesn't work anymore. You can try again by enabling sandbox mode (in FB app settings) with a developer account. It works for me.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/463219573709230?browse=search_504fc79a6ea272d92740759

Answer (score 0):

look on my solution, but it's only for posting on user wall
http://www.developers-life.com/facebook-compose-view.html